# Eclipse Installer not starting on Windows 10: SWT not found

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-10

My Eclipse IDE for java developers suddenly stopped working. When I tried to start Eclipse, I would get an error message with and address to a log file. In this log file there was some issues related to a missing library called SWT. I don't what this, so I researched on Google. I couldn't find any instructions on how to install the missing library, and it looks like this is something related to the development of desktop applications. (Anyway, I'm developing web applications, so I will not use this lib, and eclipse should be a self-contained app, IMO)

To solve the issue, I tried unninstalling eclipse and installing it again. But for my surprise the INSTALLER HAS THE SAME ISSUE!

I have spent 3 days trying to solve this without any luck.

Here is what the log file generated by the installer says:

```
!SESSION 2019-07-01 14:04:26.721 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=12.0.1
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-01 14:04:29.125
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer (137).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start() of bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.PTR_sizeof()I
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.PTR_sizeof(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.ui.UIUtil.getDisplay(UIUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.ui.UIUtil.syncExec(UIUtil.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    ... 32 more
Root exception:
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.PTR_sizeof()I
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.PTR_sizeof(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.ui.UIUtil.getDisplay(UIUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.ui.UIUtil.syncExec(UIUtil.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-07-01 14:04:29.148
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer was unable to load class org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.InstallerApplication.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:660)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1468)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer (137).
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:396)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:415)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:196)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start() of bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:863)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.PTR_sizeof()I
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.PTR_sizeof(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(C.java:22)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.ui.UIUtil.getDisplay(UIUtil.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.ui.UIUtil.syncExec(UIUtil.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.installer.SetupInstallerPlugin$Implementation.start(SetupInstallerPlugin.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:551)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
    ... 32 more
```

I am using Open JDK 12 in my environment and it was working fine. I don't know what caused the issue, since I dind't install or uninstall any software, didn't change any env variable, didn't edit any registry entries. It just stopped working.

How can I solve this?

**EDIT:** I don't have the IDE installed anymore. I'm trying to run Eclipse Installer 2019‑06 R

**EDIT 2:** I'm trying to run the 64bit version installer

**EDIT 3:** I'm using Windows 10

Comment: Which version of Eclipse were you using? Which installer did you try to use to reinstall?

Comment: I'm using the lastest stable release that is currently available in the official website

Comment: Actually, I don't have the IDE installed anymore, since I uninstalled It. What I'm trying to do now is getting the installer to run.

Comment: Which is what? I'm trying to rule out that you've gotten the wrong one.

Comment: I'm trying to run Eclipse Installer 2019‑06 R

Comment: Just a note on SWT - this is a core component of Eclipse and is always included. One part of SWT is a DLL containing 'native' code, this seems to be causing problems here.

Comment: so, how do I solve this?

Comment: Solved it by reinstalling Windows. After this project end, me and my team will never user this IDE again, ever.